# Windows 10 Remote Desktop locking up

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I upgraded my Windows 10 box to latest 16299 version (Redstone 3).

After that, I can no longer logon to this machine via Remote Desktop.

Precisely, I can logon, I can see a desktop for second, but then logon box is displated like it was screen-saver. There's my name and the password box full-screen.

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: What's error when you attempt to logon using RDP? Please confirm if your account has administrator permission.

Comment: I've got no error, when I logon, I can see desktop for brief moment, but then, on the remote desktop screen, while full-screen, it displays login box. I have admin permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

You may not be able to log on to system using either Normal Mode or Safe Mode. This occur only when Winlogon service tries to load the Windows default shell (explorer.exe) and user shell (userinit.exe) from registry. This service searches for Explorer.exe and Userinit.exe in the following path of registry:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

**RESOLUTION**

Edit these values and type the correct path of shell :

```
        Shell = explorer.exe
        Userinit=X:\windows\system32\userinit.exe
```

NOTE: These files may also be deleted by spywares. You may need to extract them using Windows CD.

Steps for rectifying this problem:

•Log on to a networked computer.
•Run Regedit.exe 
•Point your cursor to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
•Select File > Connect Remote Registry
•Type computer name (infected computer)
•Navigate to the following location in registry of destination or infected computer

```
                    HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

•Edit these two values in right pane:

```
              Shell
              Userinit
```

•Change these two values to 
                  Shell=explorer.exe 
                  Userinit = x:\windows\system32\userinit.exe

•Exit from Registry
•Restart Infected computer.
•You should be able to log on to computer.